# Telegram php bot: long script execution freezes the bot

Tags: php, heroku, bots, telegram

I'm creating a Telegram bot using PHP, and I've deployed the script to heroku.com.
Some of the commands of the bot may take more time to execute, due to while loop cycling through a big database. When the script runs for more than 30 seconds, it freezes and no commands work anymore. I have to re-deploy the script, deleting the part of code which takes longer to complete, in order to restore the bot.

Is there a limit of execution time imposed by Telegram APIs? And is there a way to extend this limit to more than one minute?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to build a workaround with background processes. This is likely a time limit on heroku, not the Telegram API.

> The timeout value is not configurable. If your server requires longer than 30 seconds to complete a given request, we recommend moving that work to a background task or worker to periodically ping your server to see if the processing request has been finished.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout